# Count unique values per each group in two columns of a data frame in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame that looks like this:

[image]

I want to count how many different targets each microRNA gets assigned to it.
So far I have tried this on R but its not working and I can't tell why

```
DT %>%
    group_by(miRNA) %>%
    length(unique((Target)))
```

I would like to get a result like this:

[image]

I can achieve this using other functions such aggregate and i have, i just don't understand what's wrong with my syntax's in this specific example.
Any help will be very much appreciated !

Comment: Try `DT %>% group_by(miRNA) %>% mutate(Target=length(unique((Target))))`

Comment: `DT %>% group_by(miRNA) %>% summarise(Target = n_distinct(Target))` should work as well.

Comment: @Duck
Yes that works with mutate. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Building the dataset and adding my comment as an answer.

```
DT <- tibble(miRNA = c("miR-10", "miR-10", "miR-10", "miR-3", "mir-7", "mir-7", "miR-22", "miR-22", "miR-22"),
             Target = c("A", "A", "B", "C", "C", "C", "A", "A", "B"))

DT %>% 
  group_by(miRNA) %>% 
  summarise(Target = n_distinct(Target))
```

Comment: Thanks, so this one doesn't do exactly what i want because it just outputs how many unique targets there are instead of giving me the table with counts. But if use mutate instead as someone else suggested it works. 
Thanks !

Comment: I am not quite sure I understand the comment. The output is the same as the desired result that is listed in the question (although it is not arranged in the same order). Glad that you got it to work though.